# Как перехватить Enter при вводе в EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня есть `EditText`, при вводе в него пробелов и Enter'ов, я должен их перехватывать. Но никак не пойму, как обозначается Enter? Пробовал перехватить его, как пробел — не помогает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter - управляющий символ, его нельзя просто так перехватить - для этого есть специальная константа в `KeyEvent`:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && 
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                // действие при перехвате Enter
            }
        return false;
    }
}
);
```

Comment: А из SQLite таблицы в `cursor` он приходит в виде чего? Как он там "помечается"? Я смотрел в таблице, там он как пробел, но в `cursor` он как передается?

Comment: Код управляющего символа Enter в текстовой строке зависит от кодировки, обычно это код 13 ( аналогично управляющая последовательность /n ). В разных операционных системах могут быть разные управляющие символы перевода строки. При "просмотре" строки он не отображается , поэтому вы видите "пробел"

Comment: То есть, нужно посмотреть как он отмечается в SQLite базе данных, а потом в `Cursor` перехватить управляющий символ?

Comment: Я не знаю, что вы хотите делать, но судя по всему - да.

Comment: вот [таблица управляющих кодов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Управляющие_символы) - разбирайтесь. Кстати, я ошибся, управляющая последовательность Enter не `/n`, а `/r`.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду разбираться :).