# Как правильно реализовать callback в RecyclerView (EditText) событие addTextChangedListener?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть список `recyclerview (textView, EDITTEXT)`. Мне нужно реализовать событие `addTextChangedListener`.

Например, при вводе текста в  `EditText` (на какой нибудь элемент списка), я хочу чтобы значение других `EditText` изменились. Например, если в `onTextChanged` попытаться вызвать `edittext.settext`, получится бесконечная рекурсия (т.к если мы изменим значение какого либо элемента, будет вызываться `addTextChangedListener`).

Как мне сделать так, чтобы я мог обращаться к элементам списка по индексу? Или может есть другие способы?

Вот мой код:

```
public class Converter {
    private  String mTitle;
    private  String mvTitle;
    private  Double mKey;
    private  Double mValue;
    public Converter(String title, Double key, Double value, String vtitle){
        mTitle = title;
        mKey = key;
        mValue = value;
        mvTitle = vtitle;
    }
    public String getvTitle(){
        return mvTitle;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return mTitle;
    }
    public Double getKey(){
        return mKey;
    }
    public Double getValue(){
        return mValue;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Converter> createConvertedList() {
        ArrayList<Converter> lengths = new ArrayList<Converter>();
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар1",1.0,0.00001,"аа"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар2",1.0,0.01,"m"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар3",1.0,0.1,"dm"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар4",1.0,1.0,"mm"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар5",1.0,0.00001,"аа"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар6",1.0,0.01,"m"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар7",1.0,0.1,"dm"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар8",1.0,1.0,"mm"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар9",1.0,0.01,"m"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар10",1.0,0.1,"dm"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар11",1.0,1.0,"mm"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар12",1.0,0.01,"m"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар13",1.0,0.1,"dm"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар14",1.0,1.0,"mm"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар15",1.0,0.00001,"аа"));
        lengths.add(new Converter("Товар16",1.0,0.00001,"аа"));

        return lengths;
    }
}
```

Код Адаптера:

```
public class ConvertAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConvertAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Converter> conv;
    ArrayList <TextView> k = new ArrayList<>();
    public ConvertAdapter(List<Converter> myList) {
        conv = myList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        // Inflate the custom layout
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycle, viewGroup, false);
        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        //k.add(i,viewHolder.textView);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ConvertAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        k.add(i,viewHolder.textView);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(conv.get(i).getTitle());
        viewHolder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return conv.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        public EditText editText;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        }
    }
}
```

и Активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Converter> conv;
    private ArrayList<String> titles;
    private ArrayList<Double> keys;
    private ArrayList<Double> values;
    private ArrayList<String>  vtitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView rvConv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);

        conv = Converter.createConvertedList();
        ConvertAdapter adapter = new ConvertAdapter(conv);

        rvConv.setAdapter(adapter);
        rvConv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

[image: вот программа]

Comment: вам нужно "ловиь" не весь ввод, а только [нажатие Enter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462178/177345) или [потерю фокуса в EditText](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446178/177345), что будет признаком завершения ввода, смотря как у вас будет организована логика окончания ввода в поле - по этим событиям изменять другие EditText. Учитывая, что ввод в одном месте изменяет значения в других местах, его лучше явно поддтверждать, то есть первый вариант

Comment: @pavlofff, такая реализация всё-равно будет приводить к рекурсии, ведь слушатели никто не отключал. Тут надо действовать тоньше, например на момент установки текста по остальным полям нужно отключать слушатель или делать проверку на id.

Comment: @Valeriy откуда появится рекурсия, если поле ввода реагирует только на нажатие кнопки enter (KeyListener)? Срабатывать он будет только в том поле ввода, в котором нажали, а не во всех полях списка (так же, как клик срабатывает только в одном айтеме списка, а не во всех сразу). никакие слушатели на вводимые символы (TextChangeListener) тут не нужны

Comment: @pavlofff, таким образом согласен. Если не будет слушателя на изменение текста не будет проблем. Но я думаю что об этом стоило уточнить, так как спрашивающий скорее всего будет реализовать так как он сделал изначально и просто добавит вашу реализацию. И я думаю что ваш комментарий стоит переместить в ответ.